# .htaccess call index.php with mydomain.com/mypage/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess contains the following code in order to call index.php?pname=contact with this url http://www.example.com/contact.html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ ?pname=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

I added the following code, so that it works with this this url (http://www.example.com/contact/), too:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*?([^\.\/]*)/?$ ?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I don't want that the contact page is accessible via multiple urls.
How can I include a 301 redirect, so that www.example.com/contact.html and www.example.com/contact will both be redirected to www.example.com/contact/?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1/ [L,QSA,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*?([^\.\/]*)$ /$1/ [L,QSA,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*?([^\.\/]*)/$ ?pname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The R option does a redirect.

Comment: Thanks antoyo, I had to edit your solution to get it working. I can't answer my own question in the next 6 hours, because stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do that. But I will post my answer tomorrow!